# Channel Files upload button console error

Tags: devdemon, channel-files

I have an issue in Channel Files 5.2.9 in ExpressionEngine 2.8.1.
Please follow my attached screenshot with dev console log which has error.
This issue was found in template in new entry form. In this case the “upload” button in upload form is not active.

Do you have any ideas?
Thank you for help.[image]

Answer (score 1):

When I experienced similar issues, the solution boiled down to jQuery conflicts.

If you are using `include_jquery="yes"` in your Channel Form tags, make sure you haven't included jQuery via a `<script>` tag anywhere else on the page.

If you use `include_jquery="no"`, make sure that you *have* defined jQuery, and make sure you're using the 1.8 branch. (1.9 removed a deprecated "msie" property that Channel Form uses.)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Channel Files in Channel Form on a template you have to be careful in setup. The control panel uses an older version of jQuery and attaches several libraries so certain functions occur. I recommend on your Channel Form page you load the included CP libraries, otherwise you will need to match the same options with compatible libraries.

Start by removing on this template any of your own jQuery stuff and use the default Channel Forms libraries. If everything works, you can try swapping items out and see what breaks it. However, like I said before, using the build in libraries will just be easier.